# Kylin Build Cube failed somtimes at" #19 Step Name: Hive Cleanup" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read kylin_hive_conf.xml

Tags: cube, kylin

The error occurs sometimes ,and after reboot kylin(kylin.sh stop and then kylin.sh start), it will find the conf dir location and pass this step.

I am using Kylin version "2.6.2", and KYLIN_CONF="/opt/kylin/conf" is already set correctly.

The errors hints are different , as i have countered the following:
1.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read kylin_hive_conf.xml at '/opt/apache-kylin-2.6.2-bin-hadoop3/bin/meta/kylin_hive_conf.xml'
    at org.apache.kylin.common.util.SourceConfigurationUtil.loadXmlConfiguration(SourceConfigurationUtil.java:88)
    at org.apache.kylin.common.util.SourceConfigurationUtil.loadHiveConfiguration(SourceConfigurationUtil.java:61)
    at org.apache.kylin.common.util.HiveCmdBuilder.<init>(HiveCmdBuilder.java:48)
    at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.GarbageCollectionStep.cleanUpIntermediateFlatTable(GarbageCollectionStep.java:63)
    at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.GarbageCollectionStep.doWork(GarbageCollectionStep.java:49)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:167)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.DefaultChainedExecutable.doWork(DefaultChainedExecutable.java:71)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:167)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.impl.threadpool.DefaultScheduler$JobRunner.run(DefaultScheduler.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

2.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read kylin_hive_conf.xml at '/opt/apache-kylin-2.6.2-bin-hadoop3/bin/meta/kylin_hive_conf.xml'
```

3.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read kylin_hive_conf.xml at '/opt/apache-kylin-2.6.2-bin-hadoop3/conf/meta/kylin_hive_conf.xml'
```

who can kindly help me find the root cause and fix this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solve the issue. I had encounter same problem and investigated about it.

Prefer to https://github.com/apache/kylin/blob/kylin-2.6.2/engine-mr/src/main/java/org/apache/kylin/engine/mr/common/AbstractHadoopJob.java#L481

When we use MapReduce, KYLIN_CONF will be set to different folder.

```
System.setProperty(KylinConfig.KYLIN_CONF, metaDir.getAbsolutePath());
```

I think to workaround with it, we have to create simple link for all XML xml configurations.

Try to check your Kylin log

```
cat YOUR_PATH/apache-kylin-2.6.3-bin-hbase1x/logs/kylin.log | grep "The absolute path"
```

You possibly see the result

```
2019-10-14 23:47:04,438 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] common.AbstractHadoopJob:482 : The absolute path for meta dir is /SOME_FOLDER/meta
```